# Using a pointer to a local variable in Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, dynamic, variables, local

I am having trouble with dynamic SQL. 
Early in my code I assign data to a bunch of local variables. 
I want to access these later in my code and use the data values. 
The code example below shows a simplified example to explain what I am trying to do.

```
-- ----------------------------------------------
-- Declare and set the data into a local variable
-- ----------------------------------------------
DECLARE @SD1  real
SET @SD1 = 1.1

-- ----------------------------------------------------------
-- Declare and set a variable to point to data local variable
-- ----------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @SDName varchar
SET @SDName = '@SD1'

-- ---------------------------------------
-- Declare and set the dynamic SQL command
-- ----------------------------------------
DECLARE @SQLCmd varchar
SET @SQLCmd  = 'SELECT MyNumber = ' + @SDName
```

By running this code the @SQLCmd contains the following ...

```
SELECT MyNumber = @SD1
```

BUT what I REALLY want is for @SQLCmd to contain this ...

```
SELECT MyNumber = 1.1
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried not quoting `@SD1` in the `@SDName` declaration?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @SQLCmd varchar
SET @SQLCmd  = 'SELECT MyNumber = ' + CAST(@SD1 AS VARCHAR)
```

VARCHAR defaults to 30 characters I believe which should be large enough. If you want to make this a parameterized query you could execute it using sp_executesql and pass the parameter value in.

Answer (score 0):

.

```
DECLARE @SD1  real
    SET @SD1 = 1.1

DECLARE @SQLCmd nvarchar
    SET @SQLCmd = 'SELECT MyNumber = CAST(@SDName AS varchar)'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQLCmd, N'@SDName real', @SD1
```